# How does gcc treat two functions with different optimizations, when one calls the other?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

I searched for a while for an answer for this question, and if it already exists please point me to the right place.

I am investigating optimizing single functions in c compiled with gcc.

I have been able to optimize a single function outside of the general file optimization using:

```
void __attribute__((optimize("Os"))) Func( void )
{
...
}
```

But I am unsure of how gcc handles:

```
void __attribute__((optimize("Os"))) Func1( void )
{
...
}

void __attribute__((optimize("O3"))) Func2( void )
{
   Func1();
...
}
```

Since Func1() is being compiled with -Os it shouldn't be inlined, and I was fairly sure that I would find that I ended up with a result where everything in Func2() optimized to -03, except for the call to Func1().  But the results I am seeing say otherwise.  This leads me to believe that I am doing something wrong or don't understand the implementation of gcc correctly.

Does the -O3 optimization attribute on func2() get applied to everything inside Func2(), which would separately compile func1() with -03 for use of inlining inside the func2() call?

Comment: You probably know this already, you can compile with "-S" to see compiled code in assembler.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be inlined if the compiler thinks that would be efficient? If you don't want that, iirc there's a `no_inline` attribute, though I probably have the name wrong. Check the documentation.

Comment: "(...) which would separately compile func1() with -03 for use of inlining inside the func2() call"  I don't think the optimisation level propagates to child functions : think of a library function that is already compiled. Anyway, I don't think -O3 guarantees that `Func1`is inlined.